# Onpress method in a list item using React native

Tags: javascript, react-native

*hi everyone 
i am new in React native programming and Java script i want to build a list item and when i press an item i should go to another screen i used the method onPress                 *
*but it doesn't work i hope that i will find the answer here as soon as possible:   *

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Image , StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
import { Icon,navigationOptions } from 'react-native-elements';


export default class HomeScreen extends Component {


goToOtherScreen(ScreenName) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Item');
 }

 render() {
let pic = {
  uri: 'https://www.lscoiffure.fr/images/assistance.jpg'
};
return (

  <View style={styles.container}>
    //Image "jai utilisé juste une autre photo pour essayer"
  <View>
    <Image source={pic} style={{width: 350, height: 200}}
    />
    //Text(title)
    <View style={{position: 'absolute', left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, justifyContent: 'center',marginBottom:20, alignItems: 'center'}}>
 <Text style={{color :'#ffffff',fontSize:24}}>Assistance</Text>
</View>
   </View>

    {

  list.map((item, i) => (
    <ListItem

      key={i}
      title={item.title}
      leftIcon={{ name: item.icon ,color:'black'}}
      onPress={() => this.goToOtherScreen(item.ScreenName)}
    />
  ))
}
  </View>
);
 }
}

const list = [
{
title: 'Appeler le service clientèle',
icon: 'perm-phone-msg',
ScreenName : 'SecondScreen',
},
 {
title: 'FAQ',
icon: 'help'
  },
 {
title: 'Conditions et mentions légal',
icon :'error'
  },

 ]


   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
 flex: 1,
  backgroundColor:'#ffffff'

 },
 item: {
padding: 50,
fontSize: 18,
height: 44,
 },

 })
```

please help me to know where is my mistake

Comment: change `this.props.navigation.navigate('Item')` to `this.props.navigation.navigate(ScreenName)`

Answer (score 2):

Change this in your code

```
goToOtherScreen(ScreenName) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate(ScreenName);
     }
```